# How to filter suggested relations in dropdown list in Strapi?

Tags: strapi

I create regular content type X by means of standart functionality. Then in another content type Y I add X as a relation. Is there any possibility to filter the list of suggested relations in dropdown list? Some option 'filter' or 'where'? If I would decided to create something like strapi I would place it somewhere here (configure the view):
[image]

It could be some field, called "where" or "filter". Is there something like that?

Or maybe there is some possibility to attach custom controller method to suggestions?

Comment: Are you asking about filtering the content types for relations in the content type builder or filtering objects of a given type in the object builder (content manager)?


If when creating an object of type Y, you want to add a relation to an object of type X but filter the selection list based on some attribute of a given X-type object. You can use REST API calls to generate a filtered list and create the new object with a selection from that list.

Comment: Yes but how do you integrate that with the model schema / admin panel Content Manager?